# How copy state of react-table to use value of page and pageSize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, server-side, react-table

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table lib. have to fetch data for a table by the filters of the column.
filter below:

```
      ...
      filterable: true,
      Filter: () => {
        return (
          <input
            ...
            onChange={e => this.handleSearchInput(e)}
          />
        );
      }
```

**handleSearchInput** method calls request to the server

```
    let params = {
      filter_fields: this.state.filter, 
      page_size: this.state.pageSize, //here should be state of a table 
      page: this.state.page  // e.g. **state.page** and state - should be arguments
    };
    Actions.getMUsers(params)...
```

so how should synchronize page and pageSize value from ReactTable component to use it in the request body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have `pageSize` and `page` in your initial component state, you can use some of ReactTable's built in props to handle page size changes and page changes:

```
<ReactTable
    pageSizeOptions={this.state.pageSizeOptions} //Don't need this if you don't want it
    defaultPageSize={this.state.pageSize} // probably smart to have if you're using this as part of a query but not neccessary
    pageSize={this.state.pageSize}
    page={this.state.page}
    onPageChange={page => this.setState({page: page})
    onPageSizeChange={(pageSize, page) => {
      this.setState({ pageSize: pageSize, page: page });
    }}
    ...otherProps
/>
```

Some important things to remember are that if you are updating the `onPageChange` and`onPageSizeChange` functions, you **MUST** also handle the page and pageSize props manually (just by setting them to the state value, as it appears above)

Also shown above, you can give it a list of the page size options you'd like to include, and have a default page size by initializing your state's `pageSize` variable with a value (like `25`)

Comment: what should be in a this.state.checkPageSize?

Comment: Sorry my bad, that should just be pageSize, I've updated my answer